# Rotate the Raspberry Pi 7" touchscreen

Tags: pi-4, screen

I want to rotate my rPi screen 180 degrees, and using `lcd_rotate=2` works during boot, but during the startup messages, it flips back again.

How can I rotate the screen 180 degrees?

I am running `/etc/debian_version` 11.5 on a Raspberry Pi 4.

Answer (score 0):

After quite some playing, I found the following range of settings to work:

1. In `/boot/config.txt`:

   ```
   dtoverlay=rpi-ft5406
   lcd_rotate=2
   ```
2. Add this in `/boot/cmdline.txt`:

   ```
   video=DSI-1:800x600M@60,rotate=180
   ```